# SQL Count/sum multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use count/ sum multiple fields in a single query sample data and desired result is as listed below:

```
MemID  claimNum  ItemID PaidAmt 
123    1234      4      5
123    2309      4      5 
123    1209      4      5 
123    1209      8      2.2
123    1210      8      2.2
```

Desired result

```
MemID  count(claimNum) count(ItemID) sum(PaidAmt) 
123    3               3             15 
123    2               2             4.4
```

Comment: Why are you counting both claims and items?  Also, this  is a simple aggregation query, so you should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to group by both MemID and ItemID:

```
select MemID, count(claimNum), count(ItemID), sum(PaidAmt) 
  from the_table 
group by MemID, ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by ItemID

```
select MemID, count(claimNum), count(ItemID), sum(PaidAmt) 
from my_table 
group by MemID, ItemID
```